# What's an elegant way to unify X,Y with (1,2), (1,-2), (-1,2), (-1,-2), (2,1), (2,-1) , (-2,1), (-2,-1)?

Tags: prolog, unification

What's an elegant way to unify X,Y with  (1,2), (1,-2),  (-1,2), (-1,-2),  (2,1), (2,-1) , (-2,1), (-2,-1)?

Doing it this way seems error prone and tedious:

```
foo(1,2).
foo(1,-2).
foo(-1,-2).
...
...
...
```

And this way seems too expensive:

```
foo(X,Y) :-
  L = [1,-1,2,-2],
  member(X,L),
  member(Y,L),
  abs(X,X1), abs(Y,Y1),
  X1 =\= Y1.
```

Comment: This might need a bit of clarification. :P

Comment: I was about to suggest something similar to your second "expensive" case... maybe you could use the second case once to add the "unrolled" predicates to the knowledge base?

Comment: by using findall(..,foo,..) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A further development on what was commented:

```
generate_pairs_foo(X,Y) :-
  L = [1,-1,2,-2],
  member(X,L),
  member(Y,L),
  abs(X,X1), abs(Y,Y1),
  X1 =\= Y1.

assert_all_foo([]).

assert_all_foo([(X,Y)|T]) :-
  assert(foo(X,Y)), assert_all_foo(T).

find_all((X,Y),generate_pairs_foo(X,Y),L), assert_all_foo(L).
```

Hmmmmmm... look, it's easier and shorter to just write all the cases xD

Comment: I really think the other's answers are clearer... maybe you should accept one of them (unless you're looking for a solution to bigger and more general cases that cannot be handled that way).

Answer (score 3):

```
foo0(X,Y):-
    member(X,[1,-1]),
    member(Y,[2,-2]).

foo(X,Y):-
    foo0(X,Y);
    foo0(Y,X).
```

Answer (score 1):

Using member/2 this way is kind of a **Prolog anti pattern**. Although 
member/2 is short, usually member/2 cannot do clause indexing.

You can try your self and compare these two solutions:

Foo Member:

```
foo_member0(X,Y):-
    member(X,[1,-1]),
    member(Y,[2,-2]).

foo_member(X,Y):-
    foo_member0(X,Y);
    foo_member0(Y,X).
```

Foo Clause:

```
foo_clause0(1).
foo_clause0(-1).

foo_clause1(2).
foo_clause1(-2).

foo_clause2(X,Y) :- foo_clause0(X), foo_clause1(Y).

foo_clause(X,Y) :- foo_clause2(X,Y).
foo_clause(X,Y) :- foo_clause2(Y,X).
```

Now run it in GNU Prolog:

```
| ?- between(1,1000000,_), foo_member(-2,-1), fail; true.
(516 ms) yes

| ?- between(1,1000000,_), foo_clause(-2,-1), fail; true.
(375 ms) yes
```

Well, the situation might change if some Prolog starts automatically compiling member/1 into clauses, when the second argument is ground.